# Install Ubuntu splitted in two devices i.e. HDD and SD card

Tags: installation

Can I install Ubuntu so that most accessed files reside on SSD 2GB (old Ausus eee 2Gb) and remainder of files reside on large SD card in card slot?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Ubuntu Desktop System requirements say that you need [5GB of disk space](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition). But they also mention that hard drive memory issues can be resolved by using a Live System. If you want to do that you might want to try a [Persistent Live USB installation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent). But here's the catch: Such a system uses a lot of RAM. So, checking your RAM capacities is probably a good idea.

Comment: @Wilzer, does that help?